# how nuodb manages the storage size increase

Tags: storage, nuodb

Say my data store is going to increase in size, if the data increases how storage manager would manage the data. Does storage manager split the data with different domain machines ( definitely that is not the case)?

How exactly would the process work? What is the recommendation in this area, key-value store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a storage manager that is soon to run out of disk space, you can startup a new storage manager with a larger disk subsystem or that points to extensible cloud storage such as Amazon S3.   Once the new storage manager is up-to-date the old one can be taken offline.  This entire operation can be done while the database is running.  Generally, we also recommend that you always run with at least 2 storage managers for redundancy.

If you have more questions, feel free to direct them to the NuoDB forum:

http://www.nuodb.com/community

Comment: Thanks that answers my question..One quick thing if you know.. if I add a S3 while there is existing storage manager with file system. How the data get synced.. any idea...

Comment: Sorry for the delay with my response. When you spin up an additional Storage Manager(SM) on S3 or elsewhere, the new SM will automatically communicate with the existing SM and begin to sync the data. You don't have to do anything special, it's mostly fire and forget. You can choose to dump the data from the original SM and load it to the second, that way the synch process (which happens every time the SM starts) would be faster - this would effectively be a delta update.

Answer (score 0):

NuoDB supports multiple back-end storage devices, including the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). If you start a broker configured for HDFS, you can use HDFS tools to expand distributed storage on-the-fly and there's no need for any NuoDB admin operations. As Duke described, you can transition from a file-based Storage Manager to an HDFS one without interrupting services.

NuoDB interfaces with the storage layer using filesystem semantics for discrete storage units called "atoms".  These map easily into the HDFS directory structure, simplifying administration on that end.

Comment: Thanks Dave.. However please let me understand, whether HDFS layer would put more burden on the performance.. HDFS which is mainly caters to write once and retrieve kind of system.. Would it be best suited for Nuodb which is planning to cater to transaction oriented system. Or I am too off the mark here.. Appreciate your thought on this..